# Apache freezes if a request is sent while leaving wifi network

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I'm using Apache 2.4.4 as a part of WAMP in Windows 2008 server. If I try to send a request while on the fringe of a wifi network using a smart phone and the phone transitions from wifi to 4g, my entire Apache service will freeze until it is restarted. Nothing is written to the access log or error log after the service stops working.

Is there a way to protect my server against this?

Edit:

I did some more testing. This only occurs if I'm using the external IP to connect to the server ie. 60.60.60.60:8080, but not 192.168.0.5:8080.

I am able to recreate the issue 100% if I stand somewhere with slight packet loss (2%), send a request, and disconnect from wifi before a response is received.

The only thing that locks up is Apache. Everything else on the server works fine.

Comment: This is a little surprising, since (in the typical setup at least) the apache http server spawns several processes serving different the requests (called 'childs'). Even if there was a problem here, how should that freeze _all_ processes? This sounds more like an OS problem to me, whatever problem it turns out to be in the end...

Comment: I'm a little confused by it too. It seems to be handling multiple requests fine. If I spam a simple request and then do a long request from another client, it doesn't effect the speed of my spammed requests. I updated the OP to include that this only happens if I use my network's external IP, so maybe it's something to do with my router? Apache still logs its shutdown signal, so it can't be completely frozen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is an issue with Apache, Windows, and my network card. I tried the solution to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549404/apache-2-4-2-2-4-4-on-wamp-windows-server-2008-r2-stops-responding-to-reques) which is a general solution for buggy Windows/Apache interactions. I'll try updating my network card drivers when I get that chance and that may also solve the issue without needing the above fix.